# How to find cash cycling circles of defined length in Neo4j?

Tags: graph, neo4j, transactions, cypher

I would like to find circles like this **a1->a2->a3->a1** where each transaction differs by less than 20% from the previous one. The below query works well.

My question is: How do I make it more generic by parametrising circle length?

```
match p=(a1:Account { id:'123'})-[t1:Transaction]->(a2:Account)-[t2:Transaction]->(a3:Account)-[t3:Transaction]->(a1)
where a1<>a2<>a3<>a1
  and 0.8*t1.amount<t2.amount<1.2*t1.amount
  and 0.8*t2.amount<t3.amount<1.2*t2.amount
  and 0.8*t3.amount<t1.amount<1.2*t3.amount
return p
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can use variable-length path pattern:

```
match (a1:Account { id:'123'}) with a1
match p = (a1)-[:Transaction*3..3]->(a1)
      where all( n in nodes(p) where 'Account' in labels(n) )
return p
```

Second, the condition can also be moved to the statement `all`:

```
match (a1:Account { id:'123'}) 
with a1
match p = (a1)-[:Transaction*3..3]->(a1)
      where all( n in nodes(p) where 'Account' in labels(n) ) 
with p, 
     relationships(p) + head(relationships(p)) as txs
     where all( i in range(1,length(p)) 
                 where 0.8*txs[i-1].amount<txs[i].amount<1.2*txs[i-1].amount
           )
return p
```

**Upd**. If you want to check for uniqueness nodes in the path (except for the first and last node):

```
match (a1:Account { id:'123'}) 
with a1
match p = (a1)-[:Transaction*3..3]->(a1)
      where all( n in nodes(p) where 'Account' in labels(n) ) 
with p,
     relationships(p) + head(relationships(p)) as txs,
     tail(nodes(p)) as nds
     where all( i in range(1,length(p)) 
                where (0.8*txs[i-1].amount<txs[i].amount<1.2*txs[i-1].amount) and
                       reduce(s=0, n in nds | 
                              s + case when n = nds[i-1] then 1 else 0 end
                       ) = 1
           )
return p
```

Or more simple with [`apoc collection function`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_collection_functions):

```
match (a1:Account { id:'123'}) 
with a1
match p = (a1)-[:Transaction*3..3]->(a1)
      where all( n in nodes(p) where 'Account' in labels(n) ) 
with p,
     relationships(p) + head(relationships(p)) as txs
     where all( i in range(1,length(p)) 
                 where (0.8*txs[i-1].amount<txs[i].amount<1.2*txs[i-1].amount)
           ) and
           apoc.coll.containsDuplicates(tail(nodes(p))) = false
return distinct p
```

Comment: Thanks. Variable length pattern is easy, but your second query is very helpful! Especially how you compare the amounts. Would you be able to throw in this: where a1<>a2<>a3<>a1?

Comment: @Tom Do you mean to check that all the nodes are different?